# PulseAudio sets volume automatically at login

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, openbox

PulseAudio sets the volume settings automatically at login with `Openbox` to some default values (as it seems).
How to configure `pulseaudio` and the autostart files to take the last values from the last session?

This behaviour started with the system upgrade to `Debian 12`.

Comment: hm, my pulseaudio saved its current state on termination, and uses them automagically. Interesting yours doesn't! (I say "saved" because I now use pulseaudio's successor, pipewire, which does the same)